# Deleting rows with certain relations

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have some tables :

```
/* Delete the tables if they already exist */
drop table if exists Movie;
drop table if exists Reviewer;
drop table if exists Rating;

/* Create the schema for our tables */
create table Movie(mID int, title text, year int, director text);
create table Reviewer(rID int, name text);
create table Rating(rID int, mID int, stars int, ratingDate date);

/* Populate the tables with our data */
insert into Movie values(101, 'Gone with the Wind', 1939, 'Victor Fleming');
insert into Movie values(102, 'Star Wars', 1977, 'George Lucas');
insert into Movie values(103, 'The Sound of Music', 1965, 'Robert Wise');
insert into Movie values(104, 'E.T.', 1982, 'Steven Spielberg');
insert into Movie values(105, 'Titanic', 1997, 'James Cameron');
insert into Movie values(106, 'Snow White', 1937, null);
insert into Movie values(107, 'Avatar', 2009, 'James Cameron');
insert into Movie values(108, 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', 1981, 'Steven Spielberg');

insert into Reviewer values(201, 'Sarah Martinez');
insert into Reviewer values(202, 'Daniel Lewis');
insert into Reviewer values(203, 'Brittany Harris');
insert into Reviewer values(204, 'Mike Anderson');
insert into Reviewer values(205, 'Chris Jackson');
insert into Reviewer values(206, 'Elizabeth Thomas');
insert into Reviewer values(207, 'James Cameron');
insert into Reviewer values(208, 'Ashley White');

insert into Rating values(201, 101, 2, '2011-01-22');
insert into Rating values(201, 101, 4, '2011-01-27');
insert into Rating values(202, 106, 4, null);
insert into Rating values(203, 103, 2, '2011-01-20');
insert into Rating values(203, 108, 4, '2011-01-12');
insert into Rating values(203, 108, 2, '2011-01-30');
insert into Rating values(204, 101, 3, '2011-01-09');
insert into Rating values(205, 103, 3, '2011-01-27');
insert into Rating values(205, 104, 2, '2011-01-22');
insert into Rating values(205, 108, 4, null);
insert into Rating values(206, 107, 3, '2011-01-15');
insert into Rating values(206, 106, 5, '2011-01-19');
insert into Rating values(207, 107, 5, '2011-01-20');
insert into Rating values(208, 104, 3, '2011-01-02');
```

I'll need to write a query that deletes rows from Rating table where the movie's year is before 1970 or after 2000, and the rating is fewer than 4 stars.I'm stuck with this year.
First let's say year > 2000.The other is year < 1970.How can I join these two and third rating condition?

Comment: Do you mean all movies with ratings less than 4 go off. Then, in the remaining rows, those before 1970 or after 2000 go off? Do the 5 point rating movies after 2000 remain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will delete ratings for movies outside the year range [1970-2000] which have a rating fewer than 4 stars:

```
DELETE FROM Rating
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Movie 
    WHERE Movie.mID = Rating.mID 
    AND (year < 1970 OR year > 2000)
)
AND stars < 4
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b96dc/40)

Comment: @JohnRock Sure. Thanks for making life easy copying into SQL Fiddle.

Comment: It doesn't look Opera friendly?

Comment: @JohnRock Hmm? I was being serious. I have to reformat data in lot of questions on SO so SQL Fiddle's parser will take it. In your case all I had to do was copy&paste the code.

Comment: I doubted for a sec ıf I was doing wrong by posting all code but anyway,I'm happy it helps :)

Comment: @lc. if you find that there are common things you have to do regularly to get people's example data to be parsed correctly in SQL Fiddle, please file an issue on my github project for that, here: https://github.com/jakefeasel/DDLBuilder/issues be sure to include the data that isn't parsing correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: EXISTS!!! of course. Thank you, did not knew SQL was so expressive, I've been doing it wrong this whole time using just ORMs and imperative programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE r
FROM Rating r
INNER JOIN Movie m
    ON r.mID = m.mID
WHERE (m.year < 1979 OR m.year > 2000)
AND r.rating < 4
```

Should do it on most RDMSs, but not SQLite.

Comment: I don't believe SQLite supports this syntax.

Comment: Okay, thanks. In SO terms am I better to delete the answer to avoid causing anyone confusion or leave it to allow downvoting?

Comment: It is always better to delete your answer if you think it shouldn't be there rather than let it get downvoted (you can always change your mind and undelete later).

Comment: It's best to leave it for the time being as you don't have many answers and don't want to trigger the automatic ban. You can always delete it in the future... Upvoting @lc.'s comment is a way of indicating that the answer is incorrect (though it is correct for other RDBMS')

Comment: You can edit it.It isn't working for SQlite but maybe for MYSql or others??

Comment: @Ben I don't think deleting one answer will trigger a ban but I might be wrong. @GarryCairns If you edited your answer to add the missing `ON` clause in your join and qualify it that it would work for some RDBMS I don't see the true harm in leaving it.

Comment: One answer, no @lc. but the OP only has 5. Although the details aren't known if the OP does this a couple of times in the next few answer's he's likely to do so.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I've edited it and will leave it to be picked off. I don't mind downvotes, a wrong answer is a wrong answer :-).

Comment: @GarryCairns FWIW, downvotes generally mean you should go back and fix what is wrong. It's not a test and programming is more an art of learning and interacting than anything else.